# Express and BrowserSync without gulp?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, browser-sync, nodemon

I'm working on an express app. I used browserSync only to watch static files but now, I want to do the same with an express app.

I saw a lot of examples using Gulp. But i wonder if there is any solution to manage only with npm scripts? (and nodemon?)

My current scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start-server & npm run watch-js",
    "build-js": "browserify -t babelify -t aliasify -t partialify src/ | uglifyjs > public/app.js",
    "start-server": "browser-sync start --server 'public/' --files 'public/' --port 9000 --no-ui",
    "watch-js": "watchify -vd -t babelify -t aliasify -t partialify src/ -o public/app.js",
  },
```

Comment: Do you want to use an express backend in lieu of the browserSync built in server?

Comment: yes, I want to user an express server with browserSync

Comment: then you can use `browser-sync start -P` to proxy your express server. https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you to @lim-h for help, indeed it's possible to add the param `--proxy` (-P) to `browser-sync start`  [browsersync.io/docs/command-line](http://browsersync.io/docs/command-line)

You can download the demo here https://github.com/damienromito/express-sync

After start the express server, add the `--proxy` option to `browser-sync start`

---

**Example**

```
node app & browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:9000' --files 'public'"
```

corresponding app.js :

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router()

app.use(router)
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

router.all('/', function (req, res, next) {  

  res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' +
            '<html>' +
            '<head>' +
                '<title>Whyd Store</title>' +
                '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/style.css">' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body>' +
            '<p>Hello World</p>' +
            '</body>' +
            '</html>')
});

app.listen(9000);  
module.exports = app;
```

**NOTE**: To test browser-sync with this sample project, I update a style.css file in the `/public` folder

Comment: For anyone here who can't get it working (the page doesn't load): remove single quotes around an address in `--proxy 'localhost:9000'`.