# Express combined with browser-sync with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, automation, browser-sync

I am very new to the world of JavaScript and i am trying to build my development environment for the first time what i want to achieve  should be simple...

I want to run an Express server along with browser-sync for hot reloading i am not using gulp or grunt

but i keep getting this error:

```
Starting the application in the development mode...
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:3000
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
    Local: http://localhost:3000
 External: http://10.111.234.196:3000
 ------------------------------------
[BS] Watching files...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

this is what my my scripts look like in the `package.jason` file

```
"scripts": {
"prestart": "babel-node buildScripts/startMessage.js",
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel security-check open:src",
"open:src": "babel-node buildScripts/srcServer.js & browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:3000' --files 'src' --no-ui",
"security-check": "nsp check"
},
```

in the `srcServer.js` :

```
import express from 'express';
import path  from 'path';
import open  from 'open';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();


app.get('/', function(request, response){
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err){
if(err){
console.log(err);
}else{
open('http://localhost:'+ port)
}
});
```

and in the `bs-config.js` file is the default one i just changed ui to `false`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548537/express-and-browsersync-without-gulp) gave me the hint to use the proxy but i still get that error that i have no idea why ...please enlighten me i want to understand what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means you already have something running on port 3000. Likely another instance of the same project running in a different window. :)

Comment: I have killed all instance of node and tried again all what i get is an infinite loading on the browser and that error on the console... and BTW is my logic fine with having express and browser-sync all together what attracted me to browser-sync is the ability to keep hot reloading feature even when sharing is there an alternative to this?

Comment: it's finally working! but it's on a different port so now i have two tabs open one on 3000 and the other one on 3001 how to get both on the same port?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. Looks like BrowserSync is not working with Express on the same port anymore. I managed to run both of them on different ports with connect-browser-sync middleware.

It is my **server.js**:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    cors = require('cors');


// Express server
var app = module.exports = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


// BrowserSync at development host
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    var bsconf = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3001,
        https: false,
        notify: false,
        open: false,
        online: false,
        ui: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: path.join(__dirname, '/public')
        },
        files: [path.join(__dirname, '/public/**/*.{html,css,js,json}')]
    };  
    var bs = browserSync.create().init(bsconf);

    app.use(require('connect-browser-sync')(bs));
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());


// Route index.html
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});


// Starting express server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port') + '...');
});
```

On port 3000 there is an Express server (with no page auto reload). And on port 3001 there is BrowserSync server serving the same content with page auto reload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but without `npm-run-all` browser-sync automatically shifted the port to 3001. After I tried using `npm-run-all` it seemed to not automatically shift the port. So I think you have to specify it like this:

`"browser-sync": "browser-sync start--proxy=localhost:3000 --port=3001 --files=views"`

Or at least that worked for me :)